# Retaining context from in reactive streams

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

Can someone help me understand how context is passed on in reactive streams.
See below code for example:

```
Flux<Integer> expectedFluxWithContext = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .flatMap(item -> Mono.just(item).contextWrite(Context.of("traceId", item)))
        .doOnEach(signal -> System.out.println(signal.getContextView()));
```

When I run the above code I am getting the correct data as I would expect but in `doOnEach` operator the context is empty.

Can anyone help me to understand how context is shared in streams and what changes I can make to make this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

context is only available "upwards" in the pipeline as it is attached at subscribe time, and that does not know about anything downstream. It is not meant to pass things that are acquired during the pipeline execution, if you want to "pass" that, you might want to use Tuples.

For more info I suggest reading the appropriate parts of the Reactor reference guide:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context

Comment: `context is only available "upwards" in the pipeline as it is attached at subscribe time`
That cleared it up for me, I was confused because the concept was introduced to me as a map-like datastructure similar to threadlocals, and I was trying to use it for resource-cleanup.

But the context is created/populated at subscription time and available as a readonly-view during execution.